# How to load another page in the same page with get values?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xhtml

```
<form action="/load.html">
  <input type='text' name='t'/><br/>
  img<br/>
  <input type='text' name='i' value=''/><br/>
  dir<br/>
  <input type='text' name='d' value=''/><br/>
  icon<br/>
  <input type='text' name='ic' value='176'/><br/>
  <input type='submit' name='sb' value='go'/>
</form>
```

I want to get content of `/load.html` in the same page by ajax. How do I get the value of the GET from `/load.html`?

Answer (score 0):

This https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started walks you through the steps of setting up AJAX. To do so without a page reload you are going to have to use javascript, to cancel the submit and then get the form data and send it the server using the methods presented in the link.  Try implementing that and if you have any problems post a new question with the code you have tried.